# How to pass state component A to B React Native

Tags: react-native

i have two component, component A check Internet access and change connection state.

Component A

[image: Component A]

now i want pass "connection" state to B component and setstate there with a 
a new state...

Component B

[image: Component B]

now

Comment: Please include code in code blocks instead of images. Some users may not be able to read the code in the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since network state is used throughout the app, it's better to warp it at the root level.
And use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass the props.
Here `NetworkStatusContext` is used to pass network state to child components.

```
<NetworkStatusContext.Provider value={isConnected}>
       <App />
</NetworkStatusContext.Provider>
```

Then you can get the network state at any component.

```
<NetworkStatusContext.Consumer>
   {isConnected =>
     (!isConnected ? <ErrorMessageComponent/>: <SomeComponent/>
    )}
</NetworkStatusContext.Consumer>
```

For above question!

Passing props from Component A -> B

```
render(){
   return(
     <ComponentB
       connection={this.state.connection}
     />
   );
}
```

In component B you can access props as:

```
render(){
const{connection}=this.props;
   .....
```